# Using XPath on XML in Firefox Add-on

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, firefox-addon, add-on

I'm trying to create an add-on with jpm for Firefox 38, but I have a problem with using XPath that is driving me nuts - my results are either null or errors.  I have confirmed that the XML import was done properly as I can read information from the variable with commands like `xmlDoc.childNodes[1].nodeName`. Everything I've read indicates this is probably a namespace issue, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my XML from an exported PDF file (XFDF format):

```
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
  <f href="file.pdf"/>
  <fields>
    <field name="a">
      <value>YES</value>
    </field>
    <field name="b">
      <value>NO</value>
    </field>
    ...
  </fields>
  <ids original="77A8B7EBDF7C3" modified="543E6D5A8B8BAD"/>
</xfdf>
```

And this is my javascript code in the add-on:

```
var fileContent = ... // data loaded from the above file

var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextrasdomparser;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(fileContent,"text/xml");

function resolver() {
  return "http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/";
}

var name = ... // one of the names from the PDF file (e.g. 'a', 'b', 'c', etc)
var xPath = "//n:field[@name='" + name + "']/n:value";
var type = Ci.nsIDOMXPathResult.STRING_TYPE;

var nodeVal = xmlDoc.evaluate(xPath, xmlDoc, resolver, type, null);
console.log(nodeVal.stringValue);
```

I've tried changing `STRING_TYPE` to `FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE` and using `singleNodeValue`.

I've tried using `null` for the namespace parameter.

I've tried using things like `//*[local-name() = 'field']`.

I'm not all that comfortable with namespaces in general, so maybe there's something easy I'm missing.

Alternate Solution: Create a new XML variable, append the `fields` node from `xmlDoc`, and use the following XPath: `//n:field[@name='a']`.  Obviously, I need a better understanding of what's going on, but for now it works with what I've got, so I'll use it.  Still, any advice on the original problem would be very helpful.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are painful at first, but easy to tackle.

The following XPath expression will work

`//n:field[@name='a']/n:value`

The `n` prefix (any arbitrary string will work) signifies the use of namespace. It is passed as argument to the user-defined namespace resolver function. Since multiple namespaces are possible, you should take this into account. But for your sample xml just returning `http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/` works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, that works when I use the Alternate Solution I mention (I just edited the original post to reflect that), but I'm really trying to find a solution to the problem with the original javascript I posted - where I don't essentially replace the root node from `xmlDoc`.